# sails: how to get a value outside of the function

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I'm trying to get `count` value from a function and want to store in outside of the function.

```
var count;      
client.count({
                index: 'employee',
                type: 'details',
            }, function (err, response) {
                    if(err){console.log(err)}
                    count = response.count
                    console.log(count);
    });
```

console.log(count );
I want to use this count outside of the function.
Is this possible to do?

Comment: You're a cut-paste away from finding out. This will work, but isn't recommended. Ideally you should return all values using a callback.

Comment: i have searched about this issue but can,t able to find.

Comment: no its not working for me.

Comment: Can you share 'it' - the snippet you're trying?

Comment: I already shared that with my question.

Comment: Alright, try out my answer then. (Also, by my first comment I was referring to moving the `console.log` line outside the callback to see if that works.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try writing your code this way:

```
client.count({
                index: 'employee',
                type: 'details',
            }, afterCount);
function afterCount(err, count){
    if (err) console.log(err);
    // do whatever you want with count
    // if there's too much logic, split it into functions and send count as a param to them
}
```

Answer (score 2):

wrap in a function or use Promise API to refactory your code.

```
function(cb){
  var count;
  ......
  cb(count);
}
```